# Cubic interpolation for specific points using interp2 in Matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation, cubic, spatial-interpolation, bicubic

Given the following example is there a way to achieve bicubic interpolation without generating an entire finely-spaced grid?:

```
    years = [5,10,20,25,40];
    service = 1:3;
wage = [50 99 787.685
          779 795 850
          803 779 388
          886 753 486
          849 780 598];
    w = interp2(service,years,wage,1.5,37.5,'cubic')
```

> Warning: The 'cubic' method requires the grid to have a uniform
>   spacing. Switching the method from 'cubic' to 'spline' because this
>   condition is not met.

I understand the reason for the warning. So wish to find a solution by specifying particular points without having to generate an entire equally spaced surface (the data available is not equally spaced). Does not necessarily have to be interp2. I will have to run this for hundreds of surfaces and hundreds of query points so would need to be quite fast at returning "w".
Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question? Can you give the kind of input data you want to supply (and the expected output). As it stands your code works (albeit with a warning)...

Comment: you can usually ignore the warning unless it says about singularity etc. Is it giving you the correct answer? In this case, it probably automatically switches to 'spline'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using `'cubic'` interpolation method you can use [`griddata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) which is designated for interpolating scattered data, i.e. data which is not defined on uniform spaced grid:

```
years = [5,10,20,25,40];
service = 1:3;
wage = [50 99 787.685
    779 795 850
    803 779 388
    886 753 486
    849 780 598];
w = griddata(service,years,wage,1.5,37.5,'cubic')
```